# Pandas with Matplotlib switch axis

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

(Using python 3.5)
I have pandas dataframe tables with colums:

```
Price| Quantity|Price| Quantity|Price|...
2    | 1       |4    | 5       | 13  |...
```

Not when I Plot this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(my_table, their_table)
plt.show()
```

It puts price on X and Quantity on Y-axis.
How can I switch this around, so that price is on Y axis?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lreshape` with [`Series.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html):

```
print (df)
   Price  Quantity  Price  Quantity  Price  Quantity
0      2         1      4         5     13        10
1      8         7      2         3      6         8

#remove duplicates in columns adding numbers
L = ['Price', 'Quantity']
k = int(len(df.columns) / 2)
df.columns = ['{}{}'.format(x, y) for y in range(1, k+1) for x in L]
print (df)
   Price1  Quantity1  Price2  Quantity2  Price3  Quantity3
0       2          1       4          5      13         10
1       8          7       2          3       6          8

#filter columns
prices = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Price')]
quantities = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Quantity')]
print (prices)
['Price1', 'Price2', 'Price3']

print (quantities)
['Quantity1', 'Quantity2', 'Quantity3']

#reshape all values to 2 columns
df = pd.lreshape(df, {'Price':prices, 'Quantity':quantities})
print (df)
   Price  Quantity
0      2         1
1      8         7
2      4         5
3      2         3
4     13        10
5      6         8

df.set_index('Price')['Quantity'].plot()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Before I had overlaping lines - what I wanted - with this solutions it draws them sequentially

Comment: Can you explain more? Because it seems I dont understand what do you need.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c36una20ex0eh5l/Screenshot%202017-02-20%2012.33.11.png?dl=0 This is the graph I'm getting. All I need is to get the vertical lines to be horizontal. Thous lines are generated by the two dataframes that have the shape I should above.

Comment: `plt.plot(
        my_table, my_table[PRICE, 'g--',
        their_table, their_table[PRICE], 'r--'
    )` Did it!

Comment: what is ` my_table` and what `their_table` > I cannot reproduced your code.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mihkell/408ccbeae8da0ee7366e22a2ece93c41 example